# How can I include my JavaScript file into an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, django

I need to inculde my JavaScript file in django. I know how to include CSS files. I'm doing it this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'demo/style.css' %}"/>
```

How can I include my JavaScript file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do this (inline scripts and external scripts):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Inline script (option 1):
    <script>
      // your js code here
    </script>
    External script (option 2):
    <script src="your-code-file.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You are probably interested in this one:

```
<script src="your-code-file.js"></script>
```

Comment: I resolved it. Thank you.
<script src="/static/demo/js/demo.js"></script

Answer (score 4):

> I know how to include files of CSS. […] How can I include my javascript file?

One obvious answer is “Manage it the [same way as other static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/). Then include it with a `script` element, the same way you'd do any JavaScript file”.

If you've tried that, or other things, please edit your question to [say what you tried and what happened instead](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).